# C++, get future object return value before timeout

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am trying to bound the execution time of a thread with C++ thread. If a thread finished execution before the time limit I set, I should get the returned value of the thread. The code is like the following:

```
string bottomUp(future<string>& futureObj, ...) {
    while(futureObj.wait_for(chrono::milliseconds(0)) == std::future_status::timeout) {
        ...
        if (finishes) {
            return "Y";
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    promise<string> exitSignal;
    future<string> futureObj = exitSignal.get_future();
    thread th(&bottomUp, ref(futureObj), ...);
    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(3));
    exitSignal.set_value("X");
    th.join();
    cout << "Result: " << futureObj.get() << endl;
}
```

With the above code, I am expecting to get "Y" if the thread finishes before the timeout and get "X" if timeout. But by running, I always get "X" even if the thread finishes before the timeout.

Does anyone know where the problem is? Thanks!

Comment: You always do `exitSignal.set_value("X")` regardless of what happens inside the thread. Also the returned value of `bottomUp` will be completely ignored since you pass `bottomUp` to std::thread constructor.

Comment: Thanks, I guess that's the reason why I always get "X". Can I check the status of the thread to see whether it finishes? So I can choose to call set_value or not.

Comment: in the main thread: instead of setting the result, check if future is set and if not then set result (similar to what you do in bottomUp). In bottomUp: set value instead of return (you need to pass promise to bottomUp).

Comment: Thx but how to check if the future is set? I tried valid() but it's not working.

Comment: You already do that: wait_for with timeout 0.